# Problem cache with symfony during development

Tags: symfony, caching

I'm using symfony 3.4 and when I add code in controller or in twig I don't see the changes.
Anytime I have to run `php bin/console cache:clear`.
I try to add

```
twig:
    cache: false
    debug: true
```

and use app_dev.php, but without lucky

use `php bin/console server:run` to develop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't post comment on your question.

Are you sure your web server doesn't cache the content?

Comment: I'm in local and I use `php bin/console server:run`

Comment: can you check PHP cache. Most likely zend.opcache is enabled.

Comment: also check that `twig:   cache: false   debug: true` is set in both config.yaml and config_dev.yaml